# How to share config.file between Node.js server and React client app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create a general config file that will be shared between server and client code.

A good example was described [here](https://codeburst.io/node-js-best-practices-smarter-ways-to-manage-config-files-and-variables-893eef56cbefhttps://) but is only valid for a Node.js part.

Does anybody have an experience with doing smth like this? I appreciate any suggestions and advice.

Comment: I prefer to use dotenv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module for this.

Comment: user task runner, Grunt, Gulp or awesome webpack. There are somaly plugins available for you to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `.env` file and use in webpack and node.js. [Dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package loads environment variables from a `.env` file into `process.env`. To use env variable in Front-End must add [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) plugin. For example
folder structure:

```
├── _server
|   ├── index.js
├── _front-end
|   ├── webpack.js
|   └── src
└── .env
```

```
# .env file
CONFIG=test
```

node.js:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });
console.log(process.env.CONFIG); // test
```

webpack:

```
const DotenvWebpack = require('dotenv-webpack');
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });
module.exports = {
...
plugins: [... new DotenvWebpack() ...]
...
}
```

Comment: I've got the following project structure: 
- server;
- client react

where should `.env` file be defined?

Comment: I, added project structure.

Comment: when I'm trying to read `.env` file from a same level as `client react` and `server`, it gives the following error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.env`,
in root server directory it works good

Comment: In the client you should add dotenv-webpack plugin. It work for me. I use this approach in many project.

Comment: Maybe webpack config not applied.

Comment: thankyou, the reason was path to `.env` file. how I can edit webpack config if it is located in node_modules?

Comment: If you use `create react app` must eject project to write own custom webpack config. If solved your problem please endorse my  answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your client, and server code in a single project?

Using dotenv would be a solution, but if you want to do without it, this might work.

server/config/index.js [server config]

```js
const path = require("path");
const rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname , "../");
const serverPath = path.resolve(rootPath,"server");
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production";

const config = {
  development : {
    phase:"development",
    root: rootPath,
    host: "localhost",
    port: process.env.PORT || 3001,

    db:{ // you don't want client code to know this.
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3306,
        database: "db_user",
        user: "admin",
        password: "passed",

    },
    // and so on..
}
module.exports = config[env];
```

src/config/index.js [client config]

```js
import {host, port} from "../../config";

const config = {
  host,
  port,
  client_specific_config: "config"
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: my client and node are two separate projects

Comment: If so, the first line in the client config file should be modified so that it refers to the correct path of the server side config script.